# How does while loop of getline() function introduces new text line after every time while loop overs

Tags: c++, file-handling, getline

```
string line;
  search.open("1.board");
  while(getline("1.board",line))
  {
    cout<<line<<"\n";
  }
```

Like,here every time loop overs getline starts pointing to next line.
how?

Comment: The first parameter of [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is an input stream, *not* the file name.

Comment: Voting the close as off-topic, because this appears to be a simple typo.

Comment: the stringstream holds the file, and getline gets the line 1 by 1 from the stream. That is, it gets the first line every time, and once it gets it, the stringstream no longer holds it, so next call will display a new line

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of opening a file called "1.board" and using `std::getline`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    std::ifstream inputStream("1.board");

    while (std::getline(inputStream, line))
        std::cout << "Line " << ++lineNumber << ": " << line << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You can look here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline.